# Why is Sonar ignoring the NOSONAR comment in my C# code

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Java code with NOSONAR comment is ignored as expected, C# code is not.
Is there a specific configuration to do to activate the tag for C# code?

Details http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-1-12-in-screenshots/

Thanks

Comment: I surprised this got no comments or answers...